# TypeError: 'printBoardPG' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I am trying to get this connect four board to print and I have a console board and a pygame board that is displayed. I want to check the console board using a while loop to see if a player has gone somewhere and then update the pygame board accordingly. The while loops to check this though have been giving me the error

> 'TypeError: 'printBoardPG' object does not support indexing'. Could anyone help me with this mess?

```py
class printBoardPG:
    M = makeBoard()
    board = M.boardMake()
    def boardPG(board):
        pygame.init()
        while True:
            x = 0
            y = 0
            while WIDTH >= x:
                while HEIGHT >= y:
                    if board[x][y] == "X":
                        tilemap[x][y].RED
                    y += 1
                x += 1
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth * tilesize, mapheight * tilesize))
            for row in range(mapheight):
                for column in range(mapwidth):
                    backdrop1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours[tilemap[row][column]],
                                                 (column * tilesize, row * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize))


            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

printBoard()

printBoardPG().boardPG()
```

Comment: `boardPG()` accepts a `board` argument. You should be passing that as well.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is unclear what is being asked about and there is no [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @amanb No, `board` is "`self`"